# Using the default Magento 2 template block class in a Module

Tags: magento-2.1, xml

I'm tying to add a simple block to the header using the default template class with the following code

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test.trigger" template="trigger.phtml"/>
```

This is inside a container next to a custom class block I wrote so i know the containers and everything else all works. If I change the class to the same as my custom class it works.

So i can use my modules custom class and it will render out fine, how can i use the default template class without needing to extend it pointlessly in my module?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try following way:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test.trigger" template="Vendor_Module::trigger.phtml"/>
```

Comment: @Chris Morris did you try this answer?

Comment: Only just got back onto the project, seem to have worked. Thanks.